# get the data for last month if next month no data is there

Tags: mysql, join, cross-join

I want to get the data of last month if no data is there in the next month.
suppose data is:

```
stock_item month stock
pepsi      4     100
pepsi      5     120
pepsi      9     80
coca cola  4     90
coca cola  6     100
coca cola  8     120
```

the output should be like:

```
stock_item month stock
pepsi      4     100
pepsi      5     120
pepsi      6     120
pepsi      7     120
pepsi      8     120
pepsi      9     80
pepsi      10    80
coca cola  4     90
coca cola  5     90
coca cola  6     100
coca cola  7     100
coca cola  8     120
coca cola  9     120
coca cola  10    120
```

Month is between 4 and 10 because indian fiscal year starts in April and current month is October, so 10.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please consider adding more details.

Comment: I need to find the closing stock of each item, but if item has no record in  table for the month then for that stock item last value should be taken. suppose a item has stock of 420 in march and there after there is not record for that item then for all upcoming month stock should be 420.

Comment: Can you edit you post to include code you have already tried? Stack overflow does not write code for people.

Comment: @BenderBending Unfortunately, that's not strictly true.

Comment: i think you would need to use nested loop as you need to interate both items and month, or `union` if you don't have a lot of items, it's tricky either way, is there any reason why you can't do it at application level?

Comment: What version of MySQL? [MySQL 8 introduced window functions which might help](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a partial answer for how to accomplish this for a single stock.

First, create a table for the months you want and populate it. This gives us something to iterate over.

```
create table stock_months (
    int month_num not null
);
insert into stock_months values (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10);
```

Now we can select months from this table and [`left outer join`](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) with `stocks` to get all months.

```
select stock_item, month_num, stock
from stock_months sm
left outer join stocks s
    on sm.month_num = s.month and s.stock_item = 'pepsi'

+------------+-----------+-------+
| stock_item | month_num | stock |
+------------+-----------+-------+
| pepsi      |         4 |   100 |
| pepsi      |         5 |   120 |
| pepsi      |         9 |    80 |
| NULL       |         6 |  NULL |
| NULL       |         7 |  NULL |
| NULL       |         8 |  NULL |
| NULL       |        10 |  NULL |
+------------+-----------+-------+
```

We can use variables to remember the values of the previous row.

```
select
    case when stock_item is null then
        @stock_item
    else
        @stock_item := stock_item
    end as stock_item,
    month_num,
    case when stock is null then
        @stock
    else 
        @stock := stock
    end as stock
from stock_months sm
left outer join stocks s
    on sm.month_num = s.month and s.stock_item = 'pepsi'
order by month_num;

+------------+-----------+-------+
| stock_item | month_num | stock |
+------------+-----------+-------+
| pepsi      |         4 |   100 |
| pepsi      |         5 |   120 |
| pepsi      |         6 |    80 |
| pepsi      |         7 |    80 |
| pepsi      |         8 |    80 |
| pepsi      |         9 |    80 |
| pepsi      |        10 |    80 |
+------------+-----------+-------+
```

Why didn't that work? Because the `select` iterates through the results of the join in whatever order it likes. Then it sorts. In this case it did the rows with `stock_item` first.

We need to sort the joined rows first. We can do that by selecting from a subselect which is already in order.

```
select
    case when stock_item is null then
        @stock_item
    else
        @stock_item := stock_item
    end as stock_item,
    month_num,
    case when stock is null then
        @stock
    else 
        @stock := stock
    end as stock
from (
    select stock_item, month_num, stock
    from stock_months sm
    left outer join stocks s
        on sm.month_num = s.month and s.stock_item = 'pepsi'
    order by month_num
) stocks;

+------------+-----------+-------+
| stock_item | month_num | stock |
+------------+-----------+-------+
| pepsi      |         4 |   100 |
| pepsi      |         5 |   120 |
| pepsi      |         6 |   120 |
| pepsi      |         7 |   120 |
| pepsi      |         8 |   120 |
| pepsi      |         9 |    80 |
| pepsi      |        10 |    80 |
+------------+-----------+-------+
```

I'm not sure how to go from here to all stock items.